# Add a QlineEdit to a scrollArea dynamically with a push button (ideally in a certain position and size) using Pytq5 in python

Tags: python, pyqt5, widget, qt-designer

Here is my question, I want to add a QlineText widget to a predefined scroll area created with QTDesigner. This has to be done in runtime, not in the end. Such as creating a row by range such as this code

```
def CreateFields(self,NumberOfFields):
    print(NumberOfFields)

    formLayout = QFormLayout()
    groupBox = QGroupBox()
        
        for c in range(50):
            # Add text field
            Fieldname[NumberOfFields]= QLineEdit(self)
            Fieldname[NumberOfFields].setText(str(NumberOfFields))
            formLayout.addRow(Fieldname[NumberOfFields])

    groupBox.setLayout(formLayout)
    self.scrollArea.setWidget(groupBox)
```

This works relatively well, which is a function called by a push button. However, the scroll area is populated with 50 text areas when I just want to add one after the other with a push button. I can live with no formatting, but it doesn't look good. Once we solve the initial problem, I would like to tackle the format and position issue. I can do this easily in c# why not python. Remember the QscollArea is defined with scrollArea and has already a layout since it was created using QTDesigner. I have looked everywhere at the internet but no one can solve this, I know it's so simple that no one bothers. I am good at programming, but this one is perplexing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was simply putting the **formLayout = QFormLayout()** before the function. However, I wasn't able to figure how to format the text for size. It is the same size in height as in width something I don't like. No way of changing this.